# Impersonal "Se" vs. Passive "Se"

Tags: gramática, español-neutral, oraciones-pasivas-reflejas

I have a question about Impersonal "Se" vs. Passive "Se"

I have already known that sometimes it is not necessary to distinguish
but when I saw this sentence below, I started having some doubts

> EL PASADO MARTES SE INAUGURÓ LA NUEVA AUTOPISTA.

I think that it is "passive se" but is it possible to interpret "impersonal se"?

Answer (score 3):

One of the tests that you can use in this case is to observe the verb and see if it can be pluralized together with the subject. In a "passive *se*" sentence you can do it; in an impersonal sentence it's impossible (i.e. it produces an ungrammatical sentence). [The verb in impersonal sentences is always in the third person singular](http://www.rae.es/consultas/se-venden-casas-se-buscan-actores-frente-se-busca-los-culpables).

If instead of a new highway you were referring to new houses, for example, you would say:

> *El martes pasado se inauguraron las nuevas casas.*

This sentence has the same structure as your example, only the verb is in the plural to agree with the new subject. Since it's a correct grammatical sentence, then it must be a passive, and so must also your example.